# node.js app fails to deploy in appengine: gcloud app deploy to appengine fails, issues with cached base image and node cache

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

Folks

I am trying to deploy a simple node.js app onto appengine. Every time I deploy the same using gcloud deploy, I get these warning and errors in the logs. I am using the config module in node.js also to load some general environment variables I need. Any pointers apprecaited if others have come across similar runtime issues? here is log when I execute the command:

gcloud app deploy app.yaml

```
No cached base image found for entry
us.gcr.io/.../app-engine-build-cache/node-cache:f0sdafsadasdfsadfasfasdfasdf

Step #1 - "builder": INFO Cache miss on local cache for us.gcr.io/.../app-engine-build-cache/node-cache:f0sdafsadasdfsadfasfasdfasdf

....
later....
...
Step #1 - "builder": ERROR Error during upload of: us.gcr.io/.../app-engine-build-cache/node-cache:f0sdafsadasdfsadfasfasdfasdf

Finally my deploy fails
File upload done.
Updating service [myservice name]...failed.                                         
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build <number> status: FAILURE. Check the build log for errors: https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/builds/<my build number>


I am using
$gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 214.0.0
bq 2.0.34
core 2018.08.24
gsutil 4.33

$ npm --version
6.3.0
```

thanks for any pointers where things might be going wrong.

Comment: I guess you have tried *gcloud components update* before deploying just in case, right?

Comment: Is this standard or flexible environment?

Comment: I am using the standard environment. One thing I should mention is, today I had one of my colleagues use their environment (their email id) which I made part of the project, and then asked them to use the same configuration files as me and asked him to deploy.  It worked. Everything went off ok post that. Post that now I am able to deploy all these errors disappeared.

I did not try the gcloud components update

Comment: also gcloud components update does this locally only right

latest version of all installed components is installed on the local workstation.

Comment: if you see my original cloud version I pointed out, it is clearly the latest.
$ gcloud components list

Your current Cloud SDK version is: 214.0.0;
The latest available version is: 214.0.0

Comment: Yes, you are right :) 
So, once your colleague deployed it now it works fine as well to you?

Comment: yes, once my colleage deployed, everything is back to normal. Not sure how it fixed the issue but it looks like my environment tagged with my email id had some runtime issue. If someone knows the cause->effect of why this happens, it will be helpful to know what really happened.