# gloud app deploy - DENIED: Permission denied for "latest" from request

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

There is no change in permission or account used for gcloud app deploy for my NodeJS application, it last worked properly on 19th July. I tried it after couple months of gap and now gcloud app deploy throws error:

> ERROR: failed to initialize cache: failed to create image cache: accessing cache image "asia.gcr.io//app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d/users/buildpack-cache:latest": connect to repo store 'asia.gcr.io//app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d/users/buildpack-cache:latest': GET https://asia.gcr.io/v2//app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d/users/buildpack-cache/manifests/latest: DENIED: Permission denied for "latest" from request "/v2//app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d/users/buildpack-cache/manifests/latest".

Comment: Have you tried to update your Cloud SDK with the command `gcloud components update ` before trying to deploy it? Besides that, could you please give it a try following the workaround of this similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52172491/node-js-app-fails-to-deploy-in-appengine-gcloud-app-deploy-to-appengine-fails)? As this is a cache issue, it might related to your local machine or account interfering in the deploy, so, having another person trying to do it might help.

Comment: yes gcloud components update done and tried. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

it was related to billing, the payment could not be processed and GCP started showing the cryptic message. However it took few hours after successful clearance of previous payment for google to start allowing build.

Comment: in my case the credit card was invalid, started working right after I've added the new card

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when disabling and enabling the Container Registry service again (https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/containerregistry.googleapis.com) GCP showed me an error indicating that I should check my account billing. After reviewing it, I was able to upload it as usual.

Regards

Comment: Dockers are not being used in my project, is it still needs to be enabled?? Its disabled currently by default.